# Python HTTP Request URL End Slash

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the `requests` module in Python and seem to be experiencing an issue with it adding a trailing slash after the URL. I have tried removing this using different methods (replace, regex) but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Some details have been replace for privacy reason obviously :)

```
url = 'http://example.com:8000'
payload = {}
payload['summary'] = "test"
payload['service'] = 10
payload['template'] = 'XXX11112222'
payload['user_name'] = 'john_smith'
payload['justification'] = 'required'
payload['start_date'] = '1417737600'
payload['end_date'] = '1417759200'
r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
print(r.url)
```

The URL printed comes out as this.

```
http://X.X.X.X:8000/?end_date=1417759200&business_justification=required&service=10&summary=test&template=XXX11112222&user_name=john_smith&start_date=1417737600
```

And gives me this response.

```
200
400 No requested_service or service Parameter Provided
```

When I grab that URL and put it in an browser and remove the `'/'` before the `'?'` it works fine. Eg: `http://example.com:8000?....` works, however `http://example.com:8000/?...` does not. But I can't work out how to remove the trailing slash off the URL in the Python script.

Answer (score 4):

Your server is at fault here, not the `requests` library.

The HTTP RFC states, in [section 3.2.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.2):

> If the abs_path is not present in the URL, it MUST be given as "/" when used as a Request-URI for a resource

A URL without a path (such as `http://X.X.X.X:8000`) has no absolute path component, so it is set to `/` as per the standard. If your server responds differently when *no path* is given, then it is violating that standard.

There is no work-around for this, short of patching the `requests` source code to [remove the default value for the path portion of a URL](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L62-L64). This'll have to be done in [other locations too](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/packages/urllib3/util/url.py#L26-L34); I didn't do an exhaustive search.

Comment: Hi Martijn, looks like you are right, the problem stems deeper than a simple fix. Should I mark your response as correct even though my problem is not fixed? Or should I just leave it, I'm not sure what the stack etiquette is for this kind of thing :)

Comment: The checkmark means you found a post the *most helpful*. Wether or not you found my post helpful is entirely up to you! It doesn't really have to mean 'problem solved'; your *question* has been solved, of sorts.